# Can someone please explain this sentence to me, and maybe give me a quick and simple break down on casting :)

Tags: pointers, casting

I am new to C++, and could use some clarification regarding the following sentence:

> "a pointer to a struct sockaddr_in can be cast to a pointer to a struct sockaddr and vice-versa. So even though connect() wants a struct sockaddr*, you can still use a struct sockaddr_in and cast it at the last minute!"

What is meant by this statement?

Comment: 1) most probably has nothing to do with C++, sounds like C; 2) what part don't you understand?

Comment: I undertand now thanks to those great explanations. i do have another question though. How do you get domain name when using an IP for the input to getaddrinfo()? ive tryed pulling ai_canoname out but dosent seem to be anything in there when i use ip, but if i use host name it puts the ip there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have

```
struct sockaddr_in *var;
```

and you have

```
int connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
```

you can do:

```
connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *) var, addrlen);
```

This is used because those family of functions don't receive always a sockaddr_in, they can receive, for example a sockaddr_in6. So you can cast both pointers to sockaddr and they will work.

¿how? The think is that the first field of those structs is the same, if you cast them to sock_addr you can still read the first field without having and undefined behaviour, and then handle them as the specific struct defined by that field.

```
struct sockaddr {
    unsigned short    sa_family;    // address family, AF_xxx
    char              sa_data[14];  // 14 bytes of protocol address
};

struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;   // e.g. AF_INET, AF_INET6
    unsigned short   sin_port;     // e.g. htons(3490)
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;     // see struct in_addr, below
    char             sin_zero[8];  // zero this if you want to
};
```

the sa_family field will be the same as the sin_family field, so you can know if it is a AF_INET or a AF_INET6 before casting.